# How to show querystring in my angular view page without using controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used AngularJS 1. This is my stateprovider I have configured in my config.js page

**JS**

```
.state('projects', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/projects",
    templateUrl: "views/common/master_page.html",
})
.state('projects.image', {
        url: "/project-files/:unique_id?source",
        templateUrl: "views/project/project_image.html",
        data: {pageTitle: 'Project :: File Upload'},
        controller: 'addProjectCtrl',
    })
```

**And this is my URL**

```
http://somedomain.com/#/projects/project-files/e7ff36e87bc282863016f5d2887e03c6?source=helloWorld
```

**View(project_image.html)**

```
Unique : {{$stateParams.unique_id}} <br />
Source : {{$stateParams.source}}
```

I have just posted my requirement code. I want to show `unique_id` and `source` in my view page. But unable show above two data. Please help me.

Comment: wwhy don't you use path params in both like /project-files/:unique_id/:source any specific reason for query string ?

Comment: @VinodLouis This is separate things. Ok, I will do later.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use `$stateParams` in HTML. Instead, inject `$stateParams` in your `addProjectCtrl` controller.

And, have it like this in controller,

```
$scope.unique_id = $stateParams.unique_id;
$scope.source = $stateParams.source;
```

If you use `controllerAs` syntax, have it accordingly!

Now, these can be mapped in HTML,

```
<span>{{unique_id}}, {{source}}</span>
```

Comment: You are right. But I don't want to use any `$scope` in my `addProjectCtrl`. direct show page url querystring in my view.

Comment: @Chinmay235 you can use `controllerAs` syntax instead of `scope` if you want.. there is no other decent way than these two (`scope` or `controllerAs`)

Comment: @Chinmay235 I can help you with other issues happening in same code (if any)